# how to build a controller that creates an xml sitemap?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, sitemap.xml

I know this question may seem confusing and/or a duplicate question. I have searched previous questions but couldnt find one that fits my case.

I am using Codeigniter. My boss has asked me to build a controller (or if possible an application in php) that autogenerates a sitemap.xml for the site. Sitemap should follow this structure:

```
<url>
  <loc></loc>
  <changefreq></changefreq>
</url>
```

It should also include information that's not on the web, but on the database. I'm confused about this, because for what I know sitemaps are based on links from the site. (Then again, I know nothing about xml so that's a reason for all my confusion).

For example, one part of the site has a 'newsfeed', this shows the latest 5 news from the database. What my boss wants is for old news to be indexed as well.

I should point out that the site uses two different databases. One for the news on the newsfeed, and another for the rest of products in the site. (Each product has its own link, some products are not on site only on database, and my boss wants those products on sitemap either way).

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated, since I have no clue on where to start.

Thanks for your time

Comment: So you are saying you have no thoughts at all on how you may potentially approach this problem?

Comment: i'm completely lost. At first I thought of http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ to do the sitemap, but that's not it since what my boss wants is to have a controller that does it (which i dont understand at all). I'm not asking for you to do my job obviosly (sorry if it seems that way) just references as how to start this so i know what i can research for.

Comment: xml-sitemaps.com is not dynamic. Have a detailed idea below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the structure: You make a function that checks if a) sitemap.xml does not exist or b) if some definite time has passed from the creation of the file that already exists.

if a) OR b) make a NEW file sitemap.xml. This always starts like that:

```
$xml_data = '   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  ';
$xml_data .= '  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" ';
$xml_data .= '  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   ';
$xml_data .= '  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">   ';
```

Then make a query reading from db every post and page that you want to include to the sitemap. You use a loop including:

```
$xml_data .= '  <url><loc>'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.$recLink.'</loc>    ';
$xml_data .= '  <lastmod>'.$recDate.'</lastmod> ';
$xml_data .= '  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>  ';
$xml_data .= '  <priority>1.00</priority></url> ';
}
$xml_data .= ' </urlset> ';
```

Finally, you write and save the file:

```
$fh = fopen($file,'w');
fwrite($fh, ltrim($xml_data));
fclose($fh);
```

Don't forget to adjust to your code. It's not copy and paste.

Comment: Thank you very much Nik, I'm working based on your code to see if it works.

Comment: Bingo! You can use the same php concept as a function, building an rss.xml, a feed.xml and an atom.xml. Just follow their xml layouts.

Comment: I have a problem, it creates a new file but now I've realized sitemap is not updating :( This is what I did: 
`$sitemapn = is_file('./sitemapn.xml');
  if($sitemapn)
  {
   $nmod = filemtime('./sitemapn.xml');
   $ncurrent = time();
   $ndif = $ncurrent - $nmod;
   #1 day limit
     $nlimit = time() - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
  } 
  #check to see if sitemapn doesn't exist or is not updated
  if ( !$sitemapn OR $ndif >= $nlimit )
  {
   $this->createXMLSitemapn();
  }`

any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers here and in light of many search engines that look for an `xml` file named `sitemap.xml` on the root of your site. You could have a route that will map that url to a controller that will generate it.

```
$route['sitemap.xml'] = 'sitemap_controller/generate_method';
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in this existing Code Ignighter library for generating XML sitemaps.

http://www.mikesimagination.net/blog/post/29-Aug-12/Codeigniter-auto-XML-sitemap

It would likely be much better/faster to modify this existing code than to develop your own.

Comment: that actually looked more complicated since I'd had to adapt my entire code, Nik's way was a better aproach. Thanks anyway for your help! I might use that library for other projects :)